# Ruby with_advisory_lock test with multiple threads fails intermittently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I'm using the `with_advisory_lock` gem to try and ensure that a record is created only once. Here's the [github url](https://github.com/ClosureTree/with_advisory_lock) to the gem.

I have the following code, which sits in an operation class that I wrote to handle creating user subscriptions:

```rb
def create_subscription_for user
  subscription = UserSubscription.with_advisory_lock("lock_%d" % user.id) do
    UserSubscription.where({ user_id: user.id }).first_or_create
  end

  # do more stuff on that subscription
end
```

and the accompanying test:

```rb
threads = []
user = FactoryBot.create(:user)

rand(5..10).times do
  threads << Thread.new do
    subject.create_subscription_for(user)
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)

expect(UserSubscription.count).to eq(1)
```

What I expect to happen:

- The first thread to get to the block acquires the lock and creates a record.
- Any other thread that gets to the block while it's being held by another thread [waits indefinitely until the lock is released](https://github.com/ClosureTree/with_advisory_lock) (as per docs)
- As soon as the lock is released by the first thread that created the record, another thread acquires the lock and now finds the record because it was already created by the first thread.

What actually happens:

- The first thread to get to the block acquires the lock and creates a record.
- Any other thread that gets to the block while it's being held by another thread goes and executes the code in the block anyway and as a result, when running the test, it sometimes fails with a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error (I have a unique index on the table that allows for a single `user_subscription` with the same `user_id`)

What is more weird is that if I add a `sleep` for a few hundred milliseconds in my method just before the `find_or_create` method, the test never fails:

```rb
def create_subscription_for user
  subscription = UserSubscription.with_advisory_lock("lock_%d" % user.id) do
    sleep 0.2
    UserSubscription.where({ user_id: user.id }).first_or_create
  end

  # do more stuff on that subscription
end
```

My questions are: "Why is adding the `sleep 0.2` making the tests always pass?" and "Where do I look to debug this?"

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Tweaking the tests a little bit causes them to always fail:

```rb
threads = []
user = FactoryBot.create(:user)

rand(5..10).times do
  threads << Thread.new do
    sleep
    subject.create_subscription_for(user)
  end
end

until threads.all? { |t| t.status == 'sleep' }
  sleep 0.1
end

threads.each(&:wakeup)
threads.each(&:join)

expect(UserSubscription.count).to eq(1)
```

I have also wrapped `first_or_create` in a transaction, which makes the test pass and everything to work as expected:

```rb
def create_subscription_for user
  subscription = UserSubscription.with_advisory_lock("lock_%d" % user.id) do
    UserSubscription.transaction do
      UserSubscription.where({ user_id: user.id }).first_or_create
    end
  end

  # do more stuff on that subscription
end
```

So why is wrapping `first_or_create` in a transaction necessary to make things work?

Comment: Does this work for you if you have the transaction and not the advisory lock? It seems to be working for me that way even though that makes even less sense.

Comment: I need to ensure the record doesn’t get created twice, so I don’t see how only wrapping in transaction without a lock will help me do that

Comment: I agree with you and I need to accomplish the same thing which is why I'm writing a similar test and validating that the lock is in place. I would expect the test to fail without the advisory lock but it is passing w/ just a transaction and no lock.

Should check out the "Transactions and Advisory Locks" section of the gem's README. I also reposted this issue on the gem's github page. https://github.com/ClosureTree/with_advisory_lock/issues/42

Comment: Also if you are planning on upgrading to Rails 6, they've added a `create_or_find_by` to avoid race conditions https://sikac.hu/use-create-or-find-by-to-avoid-race-condition-in-rails-6-0-f44fca97d16b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you turning off transactional tests for this test case? I'm working on something similar and that proved to be important to actually simulating the concurrency.

See `uses_transaction` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/TestFixtures/ClassMethods.html

If transactions are not turned off, Rails will wrap the entire test in a transaction and this will cause all the threads to share one DB connection. Furthermore, in Postgres a session-level advisory lock can always be re-acquired within the same session. From the docs:

> If a session already holds a given advisory lock, additional requests
>   by it will always succeed, even if other sessions are awaiting the
>   lock; this statement is true regardless of whether the existing lock
>   hold and new request are at session level or transaction level.

Based on that I'm suspecting that your lock is always able to be acquired and therefore the `.first_or_create` call is always executed which results in the intermittent `RecordNotUnique` exceptions.

Comment: No, I'm not turning off transactional tests and I'm using the `truncation` strategy for `DatabaseCleaner`. I think this actually answers my question. Hopefully other people will find it helpful too. Thanks!